# AudioWorklet DOMException error when loading modules

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm working on a WebAudio application that requires AudioWorklets and needs functions from many different scripts to be used in the `process()` function. Therefore, I'm trying to load said scripts in the `processor` script (`frictionProcessor.js`) with the `import` command as shown:

```
import {MAX_ERROR, MAX_ITERATIONS} from "./utilities.js";  
class FrictionProcessor extends AudioWorkletProcessor {...}
registerProcessor('frictionProcessor', FrictionProcessor);
```

where `utilities.js` is:

```
//Constants
const MAX_ERROR = 0.001;
const MAX_ITERATIONS = 50;
const MAX_POS = 10000.0;
const LCG_MULT = 1664525;
const LCG_ADD = 1013904223;
```

This gives the error:
`Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The user aborted a request.`
This error disappears when the line with the `import` is commented, but I need to load a lot of modules (not only the one shown here), so just not using it is not a workaround.

The closest question I've found is: [AudioWorklet error: DOMException: The user aborted a request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49972336/audioworklet-error-domexception-the-user-aborted-a-request) . However, this was not of much help, because I am not sure of how to serve the worklet-processor with `application/javascript` since it is loaded with the `addModule` function.

On the other hand, I've tried the design-pattern example codes from https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/06/audio-worklet-design-pattern , and they work fine.

I'm using Chrome 69 and Web Server for Chrome as the local host.

Does anybody know why this is happening, or how to avoid it? The error is recurrent and not quite self-explanatory.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your `utilities.js` should be:

```
const MAX_ERROR = 0.001;
const MAX_ITERATIONS = 50;
const MAX_POS = 10000.0;
const LCG_MULT = 1664525;
const LCG_ADD = 1013904223;

export {
  MAX_ERROR,
  MAX_ITERATIONS,
  MAX_POS,
  LCG_MULT,
  LCG_ADD,
};
```

Also any evaluation/parse error will result in a DOMException. I agree that this this could be improved. I filed [a bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=892814) for it.