# DOMException error creating AudioWorlet with Webpack

Tags: javascript, audio, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I got an error when trying to create an AudioWorklet, but only when the project is served through webpack-dev-serve. If I serve the files directly with an http server, everything works fine. So I think it must be something related with Webpack configuration.

This is the error I get:

```
audio-meter.js:19 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to construct 'AudioWorkletNode': AudioWorkletNode cannot be created: The node name 'audio-meter' is not defined in AudioWorkletGlobalScope.
    at new AudioMeterNode (http://localhost:9999/bundle.js:9421:17)
    at Function.create (http://localhost:9999/bundle.js:9430:16)
```

I've been searching and there are some related questions, but none of them helped me to solve the problem. One of them points to a Chromium bug, but in this case the error only happens when the project is served through Webpack (I'm using worker-loader plugin):

- [AudioWorklet DOMException error when loading modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52636370/audioworklet-domexception-error-when-loading-modules)
- [AudioWorklet error: DOMException: The user aborted a request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49972336/audioworklet-error-domexception-the-user-aborted-a-request)
- [Use AudioWorklet within electron (DOMException: The user aborted a request)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52760219/use-audioworklet-within-electron-domexception-the-user-aborted-a-request)

I've set up [here](https://bitbucket.org/alvaro_maceda/notoono/src/stackoverflow/) a branch with the most simplified version of the project I've could, there are some files involved so I think you could see it better this way. To get it, please: `git clone git@bitbucket.org:alvaro_maceda/notoono.git` and `git checkout stackoverflow`.

If you run it with `npm start` it will use Webpack and, when you press the "start" button, you will see the error on the console. If you comment audio-meter.js:11 and uncomment audio-meter.js:11 and index.html:14 you can run it with `npm start http` and everything will go fine.

Could anybody give an idea about what to search or where the error could be?